# IntelliSense in Visual Studio when using Unity3d

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, syntax-highlighting, intellisense

How to add **IntelliSense** and **Syntax Highlighting** to Visual Studio 2013 when I call it from Unity3d?

Now I have a code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class cubeScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
            gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
            gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.blue;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
            gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.green;
    }
}
```

.. and it is all black

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you've seen this documentation about how to properly use Visual Studio with Unity C#: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/VisualStudioIntegration.html

Verify if you're using VS Express or Professional.

My only suggestion would be to retry those steps for your project, or look into acquiring UnityVS.  UnityVS is an asset package that you import into your Unity project, and it allows you to use Visual Studio's Debugger with Unity.

Alternatively, Sublime Text Editor has beautiful syntax highlighting for Unity C#, but does not compile or debug your code.

Best of luck.

Comment: I'm using VS Express. Thanks, I'll try to do it

Comment: If you have visual studio community 2017... go "tools -> get tools and features -> download unity tools"

Answer (score 2):

This question is rather old, but with the release of Unity 5 you can now use a full-featured version of Visual Studio for free.

I made a tutorial about it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNPU0gQohOM) (the first 3 minutes go over setting up; then it goes into a brief bit about debugging).

Essentially you can download [VS2015 Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) (for free) and use it with [Visual Studio Tools for Unity](https://www.visualstudio.com/features/unitytools-vs).

Unity 5 comes with the VS Tools when you install it, so no manual installation needed.

Comment: 1000x better than VS Express.

Comment: I edited the answer for VS2015. The video is still useful for info even if the installation method is now outdated.